# Convert Postgres raw query to Django Orm Query

Tags: django, join, django-orm

I have a userpoints table with ( user_id, total_points and total_time ) fields. If i want to get a rank list based on total_points and total_time i can do this like

```
 SELECT *,
  dense_rank() OVER (
    ORDER BY total_points DESC, total_time ASC
  ) AS rank from userpoints
```

And using django orm this can be done as

```
 UserPoints.objects.annotate(
        rank=Window(
            expression=DenseRank(),
            order_by=[F('total_points').desc(),
                      F('total_time').asc()]))
```

If i want to get a specific user_id from this i can do this by

```
SELECT *,

 from ( SELECT *,
  dense_rank() OVER (
    ORDER BY total_points DESC, userpoints.total_time ASC
  ) AS rank from userpoints ) as u INNER JOIN userpoints on u.user_id = userpoints.user_id where userpoints.user_id='users_uuid'
```

I am trying to do that as like

```
UserPoints.objects.select_related('user_id').get(
        user_id='query_user_id').annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=DenseRank(),
                order_by=[F('total_points').desc(),
                          F('total_time').asc()]))
```

but i am getting error as like

```
AttributeError: 'UserPoints' object has no attribute 'annotate'
```

How to do this second query with django orm ?

Comment: Annotate works on querysets and not single objects. You can access individual objects from annotated queryset. Refer to django docs on annotate and you will see some examples on topic. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Comment: Apart from doing a raw query is there any way to get a user rank here ?

Comment: Use `filter()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: getting this error "'UserPoints' object is not iterable" for that

Comment: Iterate over first queryset in your code. Not over single object. Based on the docs you could probably try to access let's say first object from your first annotated queryset like q[0].rank maybe? See count example on provided link.

Comment: no luck, still getting "'UserPoints' object has no attribute 'annotate'" this error.

Comment: q = UserPoints.objects.annotate(
        rank=Window(
            expression=DenseRank(),
            order_by=[F('total_points').desc(),
                      F('total_time').asc()])) and than q[0].rank or using filter() as Daniel suggested ?